# Does WinSCP support Linux ACLs?

Tags: linux, acl, winscp

A Windows desktop user is using WinSCP client to connect to a Linux server to pick and drop files. The client seems not to recognize the Access Control List (ACL) for this directory. Does WinSCP recognize Linux ACLs, or does it just do regular Linux permissions?

When the user chooses properties of the file or the parent directory on the server (using the WinSCP client) a dialog box appears allowing the user to set the owner and group of the file using a dropdown list. The primary groups show up, but not the group set by a Linux ACL. It seems like WinSCP does not have ACL support.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP still does not support the ACLs.
See https://winscp.net/tracker/74

---

You first need an SFTP server with ACL support.

The ACL is supported by SFTP version 4 and newer only. The most widespread SFTP server, used on an absolute majority of Linux distributions, is the OpenSSH. This server supports SFTP version 3 only and there seems to be no interest on their side to support later versions of the SFTP. The SFTP version 4 proposal is from 2004. The latest SFTP version is 6.

As such, it does not make much sense to support ACLs on a client side. Though there are some Windows SFTP servers that do support ACLs.

It would particularly not help you, as I assume you use the OpenSSH.